# CSS - How to make two 'top-right' elements without stacking

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put two elements on the top right of a card, but I don't want them to stack. In front of that I want them to stay next to each other but at the top right.

I've seen this [W3S page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp), more in detail the 'Positioning Text in an Image'.

[This is the example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_text_top_right) I'm using right now but only works for one element, if I add a new element with the same class they overlay each other:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .container {
                position: relative;
            }

            .topright {
                position: absolute;
                top: 8px;
                right: 16px;
                font-size: 18px;
            }

            img { 
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                opacity: 0.3;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h2>Image Text</h2>
        <p>Add some text to an image in the top right corner:</p>

        <div class="container">
            <img src="img_5terre_wide.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="1000" height="300">
            <div class="topright">Top Right</div>
            <div class="topright">Top Right overlayed</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way of automate the positioning the `topright` elements next to each other without making two classes and setting the positions manually?

Thank you.

Comment: whats your expected output ? how do you want those two element look like ?

Comment: They overlap because they both have the `position: absolute;` property with the same positioning. Change top and/or right properties for one of them, or do what the answers suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and other flex `properties` to make sure the `top-right` is not stacking each each and this way it will be `responsive` as well on modern browsers.

I would **not** suggest using `position: absolute` or custom `top` or `right` for this type of thing.

**Live Demo:**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.topright {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.top_right_item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 35%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Image Text</h2>
  <p>Add some text to an image in the top right corner:</p>

  <div class="container">
    <img src="img_5terre_wide.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="1000" height="300">
    <div class="top_right_item">
      <div class="topright">Top Right</div>
      <div class="topright">Top Right overlayed</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.topright {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

<div class="topright">
  <div>Top Right</div>
  <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

Your problem is **solved**.

What you have to do is put them in **separate divs** and wrap them in **topright** div, and set display to **flex**,thats all.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an wrapper for the two elements

```
<div class="topright-wrapper">
   <span>Top Right</span>
   <span>Top Right Right</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.topright-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```